# Counting days in jQuery datepicker - one day out for a particular week

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I've got two datetimepickers (as found at http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker) and the number of weekdays between them is calculated. This seems to work fine except for one particular week.

For example, if you choose 15/09/2014 in the first box and 22/09/2014 in the second, it will calculate 5 days as there are 5 weekdays between them. Great!

However, choose 20/10/2014 and 27/10/2014 and it will calculate 4. Also, a choice of 24/10/2014 and 27/10/2014 says that there is no difference between the dates.

I've tried lots of little changes in the code (such as changing how the weekends are figured out and suchlike) but it's a strange one as it works in every case I've tried except for that week so it's like I'm trying to fix code that works already.

I don't understand why this is happening, do you?

JS Fiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/xxbjL40q/

HTML

```
<h4>When are you off from?</h4>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstday" name="firstday">
</div>

<h4>When are you back in the office?</h4>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="backday" name="backday">
</div>

<p id="daysoffmessage">Please choose a day from both boxes. If you update your 'from' date after your 'back' date, please reselect your 'back' date to correct the day count.</p>

<input type="text" id="daycount" name="daycount">
```

JS

```
$('#firstday').datetimepicker({
    hourMin: 0,
    hourMax: 12,
    stepHour: 12,
    showMinute: false,
    showTime: false,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    constrainInput: true,
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    firstDay: 1
});

$('#backday').datetimepicker({
    hourMin: 0,
    hourMax: 12,
    stepHour: 12,
    showMinute: false,
    showTime: false,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    constrainInput: true,
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    firstDay: 1,
    onSelect: function(){
        // get the stuff
        var firstday = $('#firstday').datepicker('getDate');
        var backday = $('#backday').datepicker('getDate');

        // sort the weekends out
        var weekend_count = 0;
        for (i = firstday.valueOf(); i <= backday.valueOf(); i+= 86400000) {
            var temp = new Date(i);
            if (temp.getDay() == 0 || temp.getDay() == 6) {
                weekend_count++;
            }
        }

        // how many weekdays?
        var total = ((backday - firstday) / 86400000) - weekend_count;
        var total_1dp = total.toFixed(1);

        // put the info where I need it
        $('#daycount').val(total_1dp);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are in the UK, you need to calculate for Daylight Savings Time (e.g. on October 26th for 2014).

Comment: I would recommend using a 3rd party library for date calculation/manipulation, e.g. [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: @mccannf I had a look at moment.js but thought I had it cracked this way around. As I say, it works except for that week. Wuold DST make a difference? Just tried it for the weekend of 29th March '15 (when they go forward again) and it calculates correctly in that case.

Comment: @ScottBrown just one more thing: should I delete my answer as incorrect one, or edit it by adding found workaround?

Comment: I'd edit it if I were you, you certainly deserve an upvote and tick for the help you've given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**. So, as @ScottBrown has said, workaround is to change `hourMin` from `0` to, for example, `6`. It helps to get rid of incorrect behaviour (counting Sunday twice) during changing of "Daylight Standard Time" to "Daylight Savings Time", even though it's not an universal solution.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxbjL40q/3/).

... and my [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxbjL40q/4/) with handling error during selecting only second date and with recalculating value if the first date is changed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I'm still getting 0 if I choose 24/10 and 27/10 on your updated fiddle.

Comment: @ScottBrown I actually got `1.0` with "24/10/2014 00:00" and "27/10/2014 00:00".

Comment: Weird, this is what I've got in Firefox 31 and Chrome 37 http://i.imgur.com/vvapljT.png

Comment: @ScottBrown I also made [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxbjL40q/2/) with more correct processing of selected dates, even though it doesn't fix your mentioned problem.

Comment: Thanks, keeps things tidier! I'll use that and keep trying things.

Comment: @ScottBrown You can use `console.log` or `alert` to print `backday.valueOf()`, `firstday.valueOf()` and `weekend_count`. If you will say what these values are for you, maybe we will be able to find a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61109/discussion-between-scott-brown-and-regent).

Comment: ...after a chat, we figured out that it was daylight saving causing trouble (thanks for the nudge on that one @mccannf) and that changing the `hourMin` and `hourMax` to `6` and `18` meant that it wasn't counting Sunday twice. It's not an ideal solution, agreed, but as it's only to be held locally on an Intranet site and everyone has the same timezone, I can get away with it for now. Fiddle for this at http://jsfiddle.net/xxbjL40q/3/